# Mapping list in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am new to automapper. I have a class that has a collection of object. And I need that class to map to another object that has a different name. I need to map the employee to employeeDto. Both classes has different name and different propery name. Can they be mapped using automapper if they have a different name?

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
public class Job
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public List<WorkExperience> WorkExperience { get; set; }
}
public class WorkExperience
{
    public string NameOfCompany { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBegin { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure mapping to handle you `Jobs` list to `WorkExperience` list manually. See [Projection section](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Projection.html#) in AutoMapper documentation

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Fullname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.WorkExperience, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Jobs));

    cfg.CreateMap<Job, WorkExperience>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NameOfCompany, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateBegin, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDate))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateEnd, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDate));
});
```

Additionally, if you want to convert in the opposite direction, you can add [ReverseMap()](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) to avoid code duplication.

Comment: how about the property that has a list?

Comment: @RamppyDumppy: Create two mappings. First map property list a to property list b and then create a new mapping to map type of list a to type of list b.